# Trigger Function IF-ELSE Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION record_deleted_item() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (select number_itens from grup where NEW.gruop_id = group_id) != 0 THEN
    UPDATE gruop SET number_itens= (number_itens-1) WHERE gruop_id=NEW.gruop_id;
   END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER deleted_item
BEFORE DELETE ON item
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE record_deleted_item();
```

In my if-else clause I should check if the column value `number_items` from group table is not 0. How could I check it? The way I've done returns me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT` it into variable and compare to zero. You may also want to check if `SELECT` actually returned anything.

```
DECLARE
    ni bigint;
BEGIN
    SELECT number_itens INTO ni FROM ...;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
    END IF;
    IF NI != 0 THEN
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a conditional in there at all. If there is nothing in `grup` that matches `NEW.gruop_id = group_id` when the UPDATE just won't do anything at all so there is no need for two queries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION record_deleted_item() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE gruop SET number_itens = (number_itens - 1) WHERE gruop_id = NEW.gruop_id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The above assumes that `grup` is just a typo and you only have a `gruop` table.

Also, if this really is a DELETE trigger then you'll want to work with `OLD` instead of `NEW`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION record_deleted_item() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE gruop SET number_itens = (number_itens - 1) WHERE gruop_id = OLD.gruop_id;
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```